# There's planar graph. Prove that for every $3$ (pairwise different) vertices $u, v, w$ the inequality holds: $deg(u) + deg(v) + deg(w) \leq 2|V| + 2$

Tags: graph-theory

Let G = (V, E) be any planar graph.

Prove that for every three (pairwise different) vertices $u, v, w$ the inequality holds:

$$deg(u) + deg(v) + deg(w) \leq 2|V| + 2$$

I know that in a graph with |V| vertices, the maximum degree of each vertex is |V| − 1. Therefore it must be true that:

$$deg(u) + deg(v) + deg(w) \leq 3|V| - 3$$

For planar graphs it's true that $|V| - |E| + |F| = 2$ (Euler's equation), from that we can find the largest number of edges that a planar graph of $V$ vertices can have.

Each region defined by a drawing of graph on the plane is bounded by a cycle of the graph. If that cycle is not a triangle, we can add an edge between two opposite vertices and increase the number of edges. Therefore we conclude then that a graph with $V$ vertices with the most edges will have triangles for all its faces.

Then each face has three edges on its boundary, and the number of edge-face pairs with the edge bounding the face will be $3|F|$. But each edge bounds $2$ faces, so that the number of edge-face pairs with the edge bounding the face will also be $2|E|$.

We deduce then that $|F|= \frac{2}{3}|E|$, so that in this case we can write Euler’s formula as: $|V| – |E| + \frac{2}{3}|E| = 2 \iff 3|V| = |E| + 6$

We notice also that the number of edge-vertex pairs with the vertex in the edge, is $2|E|$ and is also the sum of the degrees of all the vertices. This tells us that the sum of the degrees of the vertices of any edge maximal planar graph is equal to $2|E|$ or $6|V| – 12$. But I don't know how to translate that into our inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a triplet $(v,w,u)$ of vertices in a planar graph *ideal* if the subgraph generated by considering only vertices adjacent to one of $v,w,u$, contains only vertices which are adjacent to at least $2$ of $v,w,u$

It suffices to prove the inequality for the subgraphs generated by ideal triplets, since if a triplet is not ideal, there is some vertex $x$ such that $x$ is adjacent to only one of $v,w,u$, in which case we can remove $x$ from the subgraph, and both sides of the inequality decrease by $1$. So we can keep removing vertices until the original triplet is ideal.

Now consider the subgraph $G'$ generated by an ideal triplet $(u,v,w)$. Since any vertex in this graph is shared by at least $2$ of $v,u,w$, define

$s_{v,w} = s_{w,v} =$ the number of vertices shared by $v$ and $w$ only in the subgraph.

Similarly define $s_{u,w}$ and $s_{v,u}$.

And let $s_{v,w,u}$ be the number of vertices shared by all $3$ of $v,w,u$.

It is clear that

$$ s_{v,u}+s_{w,u}+s_{v,w}+s_{v,w,u} \leq |V'|$$

Where $V'$ is the number of vertices of the subgraph.

And also note that

$$ s_{v,u} + s_{v,w} + s_{v,w,u} = deg(v) $$

So

$$ 2s_{v,u} + 2s_{w,u} + 2s_{v,w} + 3s_{v,w,u} = deg(v) + deg(u) + deg(w)$$

So

$$ deg(v)+deg(w)+deg(u) \leq 2|V'| + s_{v,w,u} $$

And I suspect that for a planar graph $s_{v,w,u} \leq 2$, which you can verify intuitively if you draw the star graph with $3$ vertices, and try to add $2$ more vertices shared by all $3$ original vertices, but I am not sure how to prove this part

Comment: I know this doesn't follow along the lines you were thinking, but I am not too familiar with some of the theorems you mentioned, so the partial solution was not too tractable for me

Comment: If $S_{u,v,w}$ is 3 or more doesnt that makes $K_{3,3}$?